# I'm trying to get my iPhone app into native share menus. Photo selection menu on iOS7 and other share menus

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm trying to add some import options to an app. I'd like to add my app's icon to certain menus, to allow ease of importing files into my app. 
I'm able to insert my app's icon in the "open in..." menus using CFBundleDocumentTypes. I can't find any mention of methods to get into the photo menu though. (See screen shot below)

Does anyone know how this can be done? It seems possible, because the flickr app icon was inserted there after installing the Flickr app.

thanks.

[image: Id like my apps icon in this menu]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook, Twitter and now Flickr are all system services, and thus they appear in the custom Photos share view. This is not the same as `UIDocumentInteractionController`'s options menu, which shows applications registered to open file types.